# Call procedure net7.0 Framework

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Dears, I call sp from code C#

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int userId)
{
    var userIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId);
    var query = $"exec GetSingleUserRecord @UserId";
    var getSingleData = await _db.Users
        .FromSqlRaw(query, userIdParameter)
        .ToListAsync();

    return View(getSingleData);
}
```

but get error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Customer_Statements.Models.UserEntity]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Customer_Statements.Models.UserEntity'.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)`

Its my first app, please advise me

Comment: The error complains about the return type, not calling stored procedures

Comment: ^^ That said, you probably do not want to use `ToListAsync` but something like `Single` or `First`.

Comment: `.ToListAsync();` returns a list of items while the error says the view expects a single item. If you used a LINQ query you could use `FirstAsync()`, but SP calls can't be part of another query. Use `getSingleData[0]` to return the first result. You probably need to use a better name for the result variable, eg `users` or `data`.

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure in the first place? If `UserId` is the primary key, you could write `var user= await _db.Users.FindAsync(userId);`

Comment: my first procedure returns the entire list of Гsers. now when I want to view a single record, I get the error specified above, or empty lines

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have already solved the problem? If not, is there any updated?

> my first procedure returns the entire list of Гsers. now when I want
> to view a single record,

To View the single record, you could modify the query statement as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int userId)
{
    var userIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId);
    var query = $"exec GetSingleUserRecord @UserId";
    var getSingleData = await _db.Users
        .FromSqlRaw(query, userIdParameter)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return View(getSingleData);
}
```

Then in the view page, the page model like this:

```
@model Customer_Statements.Models.UserEntity
```

If you want to view the list of items, the query statement should like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int userId)
{
    var userIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId);
    var query = $"exec GetSingleUserRecord @UserId";
    var getSingleData = await _db.Users
        .FromSqlRaw(query, userIdParameter)
        .ToListAsync();

    return View(getSingleData);
}
```

And the view page should as below:

```
@model List<Customer_Statements.Models.UserEntity>
```